# Change checkbox to be unchecked by default

Tags: php

I have the following code, which is at the end of a form, and asks visitors if they would like to sign up for a newsletter. Currently the checkbox is checked by default, but I would like to change it so it is UNchecked by default. I have tried changing it to checked="unchecked", but it's not working. I am a newbie, so please be detailed - and patient! Thank you!

```
<p>
<label for="newsletter" style="width: 53%;margin-left: 120px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="cd_request[newsletter]" value="1" checked="checked" id="newsletter">
                    I would like to receive email updates
</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Just remove the `checked="checked"`part

Comment: This question is so trivial as to not add value to Stack Overflow. This information is readily available in any number of HTML tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, Hardy! That was the solution that finally worked.

I am sorry that my question added no value; I did spend hours searching for an answer all over the place, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply remove the `checked` attribute completely.

Like:

`<input type="checkbox" name="cd_request[newsletter]" value="1" id="newsletter">`

and your full code would look like this:

```
<p>
<label for="newsletter" style="width: 53%;margin-left: 120px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="cd_request[newsletter]" value="1" id="newsletter">
                    I would like to receive email updates
</label>
</p>
```

You can get a better understanding of the `<input>` element from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

You'll notice the `checked` attribute also does not need to say `checked="checked"` it can simply be `checked`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I honestly spent hours searching the internet for an answer before posting here (and the reason I posted here, is that most search results were from here).